# JS code not working on Hostinger web builder as a custom code

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

I am a custom JS code block on a web builder tool, which would simply add a string to the header. The code is meant to retrieve the logo element from the header, append the string and render the view.

I heard that there is a common issue with Hostinger web builder where it doesn't render JS code very well because it runs it before loading the DOM. So I tried to take care of that. But for some reason, even though I added an event listener to make sure DOM loads first before running the JS code, it doesn't render properly, and the string doesn't show.

Any idea why this doesn't work -

```
// Add an event listener to the 'DOMContentLoaded' event
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  // Create a <style> element
  var styleElement = document.createElement('style');

  // Set the CSS rules
  var cssRules = `
      a.block-header-logo.block-header__logo::after {
          content: "Example Text";
          position: absolute;
          transform: translate(8rem, 0px);
          font-size: 18px;
          font-weight: bold;
          font-family: 'Montserrat';
      }

      .block-header__logo {
          align-items: center;
          justify-content: center;
      }

      @media screen and (max-width: 920px) {
          a.block-header-logo.block-header__logo::after {
              transform: translate(5rem, 0px);
          }
      }
  `;

  // Set the textContent property of the <style> element to the CSS rules
  styleElement.textContent = cssRules;

  // Insert the <style> element into the document's <head>
  document.head.appendChild(styleElement);
});
```